# Signal handler and waitpid coexisting

Tags: c, signals

I'm coding a shell in C that should support background and foreground processes.

Constraints:

- Background processes that terminate should be caught by signal handler
- No global variables can be used for communicating from signal handler
- No list of processes/pids allowed

My solution:

- Waitpid until foreground process terminates
- For background processes, immediately return to prompt
- Handler catches SIGCHLD where waitpid is used to clear process table

Problem:

- Foreground processes also trig handler causing one of two waitpids to error
- Can't solve by ignoring SIGCHLD while running foreground process, since background process might terminate during that time
- Can't find a way to make handler ignore specific pid (the foreground process started)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

> Problem:
>
> - Foreground processes also trig handler causing one of two waitpids to
>     error

This is not a problem - just leave the handler then.

```
void handler(int signum)
{
    pid_t pid;
    while (pid = waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG), pid > 0)
        fprintf(stderr, "%d terminated\n", pid);
}
```