# waitpid and signal handler, C

Tags: c, ipc, waitpid, sigaction

I tried to find an answer to my question at this post: [Signal handler and waitpid coexisting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29657624/signal-handler-and-waitpid-coexisting) but for me isn't very clear at the moment.

I try to explain my problems:

I'm trying to write a C program that concerns IPC between a parent process and its children. 
The parent process creates N child processes, then it waits for the termination in a loop like this:

```
while((pid_term = waitpid(-1, &status, 0)) != -1)
```

After X seconds, parent receives SIGALRM, then with the sigaction system call,
it catches the alarm:

```
struct sigaction act;
act.sa_handler = alarmHandler;
sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);

act.sa_flags = 0;
sigaction(SIGALRM, &act, NULL);
```

But, when the handler function returns, the waitpid also returns -1, and the parent process exits from the while loop above.
At the moment, the handler function has an empty body.

I ask myself what happened — why did `waitpid()` return -1 after the handler invocation even though most of the children are still alive? Why doesn't this happen with `signal()` function?

Comment: I don’t know why this doesn’t happen with the `signal` function unless you just use that to ignore the signal, but when a system call like `waitpid` exits with `-1` you should check `errno`, which for `waitpid` can be [one of these values](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/waitpid.2.html#ERRORS). In this case, I strongly expect the result will be `EINTR`, the system call was interrupted by a signal (in this case your `SIGALRM`). You need to re-start the `waitpid` system call; the program can’t automatically jump back into it when the signal handler returns.

Comment: The `signal()` function on different systems does things differently, depending on the legacy of that system.  The standards allow great flexibility, but almost no control, over what happens.  Using `sigaction()` allows for basically all of the legacy operations, but allows you complete control over what happens.  If you want dependable behaviour, use `sigaction()` and be specific.

Answer (score 3):

The default behavior of signal handlers established by `sigaction` is to *interrupt* blocking system calls; if you check `errno` after the alarm fires you should observe it to be set to `EINTR`.  This behavior is almost never what you want; it's only the default for backward compatibility's sake.  You can make it not do this by setting the `SA_RESTART` bit in `sa_flags`:

```
struct sigaction act;
act.sa_flags = SA_RESTART;
act.sa_handler = alarmHandler;
sigemptyset(&act.sa_mask);
sigaction(SIGALRM, &act, 0);
```

One of the most important reasons to use `sigaction` instead of `signal`, is that when you use `signal` it is *unpredictable* whether or not the signal handler will interrupt blocking system calls.  (The System V lineage picked one semantic and the BSD lineage picked the other.)

Comment: to zwol and Daniel H. You've been precious!! And you have avoided my madness!! Thanks very much, it works!!